# How to save all the variables except one inside a loop?

Tags: matlab, save, eval

I am trying to save all the variables except one inside a loop. But an error, or a wrong file extension, is always the answer MATLAB returns me.
Where am I wrong?

```
for SESSION=1:3
    for trial_number=1:10
        eval(['save data_',num2str(SESSION),'_trial_',num2str(trial_number),'.mat'...
                            ,'-regexp','^(?!(RESPONSE)$). ']);
    end
end
```

Comment: I recommend not to use the `save filename` syntax for that purpose, instead use the `save(filename,variables)` syntax and create two variables for your filename and variables first. This increases the readability of your code and allows you to print both parameters before using them, to check if they really contain what you expect.

Comment: In the example I posted, instead an error, I obtained a file with a wrong extension: data_1_trial_1.mat-regexp^(?!(RESPONSE)$). It seams that the format is mat-regexp^(?!(RESPONSE)$)

Comment: @kika how would MATLAB know where the extension ends? You have everything inside one `[...]`. You should follow Daniel's advice.

Comment: To precise my comment, it should be something like `save(filename,'-regexp',expression)` where filename and expression are your variables. Did not notice you are using regexp when reading it first.

Comment: you forgot the Apostrophe for the 'RESPONSE', didn't you?!  And as @Daniel said, you should make a variable for the filename/Directory. For example `saveDir = sprintf('data_%d_Trial_%d.mat',SESSION,trial_number)` and then you can check if the saveDir is what you expected by using `disp(saveDir)` and then use `save(saveDir,'regexp','RESPONSE');`

Comment: @kika; I saw you deleted your last comment, problem solved? If not please update your question and include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Max; yes, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **direct** issue with what you are trying to do is that when concatenating your strings, you have failed to place a space (' ') in between the filename and your `-regexp` argument.

However, I would recommend that you utilize the ability of [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) to take multiple arguments to clean things up and prevent unnecessary string concatenations:

```
save(filename, variablename)
```

Where `filename` is a path to a *.mat file and `variablename` is a string representing the variable in the workspace that you would like to save.

You can also pass your `-regexp` flag values to the `save` function. (The following example *assumes* that your regular expression is correct).

```
output_file = sprintf('data_%d_trial_%d.mat', SESSION, trial_number);
save(output_file, '-regexp', '^(?!(RESPONSE)$.')
```

The other way that you could approach this (if you don't like regexp or your matching gets too difficult for excluding multiple values), is to get a list of all variables in the workspace, remove the one that I don't want to save, and pass all the other variable names to the `save` function explicitly.

```
variables = who;
toexclude = {'variable1', 'variable2'};
variables = variables(~ismember(variables, toexclude));
save(output_file, variables{:});
```

Comment: Fantastic. The second method is the only one which works for me when I have more than one variable to exclude (I can't use clearvars as my matlab version is older than 2008a). I tried using (XXX|YYY) and other combinations with negative look around regex, without any luck. Thanks